# Is there a way to add and run a specific code during run time?

Tags: database, vb.net

I am creating controls inside [Gmaps.Net](https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/releases/view/20235) and I managed to dynamically add markers in it. One thing, I want to make the markers run different codes.

let's say I have a preset of 3 markers on the map.

```
1 - `Camera1.Show()`
2 - `Camera2.Show()`
3 - `Camera3.Show()`
```

if someone wants to add another, it should run 4 - `Camera2.Show()` or any camera that he want's to bind that marker to.

the process that is on my mind right now is, since I will be having a database for saving the markers' locations, is it possible to also save the code there is MS Access?

something like..

get this code -- `Camera5.Show()` and add it to a dynamically added button.. thanks!

**UPDATE :**  here is some of my code..

```
Dim f2c1 As New Form2
Dim f2c2 As New Form2
Dim f2c3 As New Form2
Dim camera1 As New GMapMarkerGoogleGreen(New PointLatLng(14.579929, 121.058901))


If item Is camera1 Then       ' camera1 is one of the markers that I predefined in the code
        With f2c1             ' so in terms of adding more, I need to save the new ones' latlong in DB
            If .Visible = True Then
                .Hide()
            Else
                .Show()
                .AxXHDec1.Camera = 1                           ' camera ID--needs database
                .AxXHDec1.Host = "some ip add"                 ' host address--needs database
                .AxXHDec1.Play = 1                             ' true / false
                .AxXHDec1.Command = "SetPass -4 guest guest"   ' some password
                .AxXHDec1.ShowText = 7
                .AxXHDec1.ShowInfo = 1
                map_OnMapDrag()
            End If
        End With
    End If
```

this is somewhat what I want to use again. I am thinking of adding this to a certain `function` since I am only creating instances of `Form2` as `f2c1`, `f2c2`, `f2c3` that aXxhdec is an activeX. good thing it is possible to use only one.

Comment: dont you just have to save some parameters so that the class object can be reconstituted?  your code created the object to get to that point cant it recreate them?

Comment: I don't really get what you are saying, I just put a little code so it could be simpler. what am I dealing with is a whole block of code, so maybe if I save the code to a database, it should help me 'use' that code again. is that even possible?

Comment: isnt your code reusable? cant you plug in a number of values and settings and get it to run again to get the the same point where you want to save? THATS what you really want to save are those properties/variables etc.  it doesnt matter how much code there is, it can run again and again, no?  you could serialize your objects and save that, but it doesnt save **code** but property settings.  In the end, that requires the same thing as above: reusable code with exposed and decorated properties to recreate a given object state.

Comment: so there is no such thing as saving a code for future use? rather make something that can be used again in general term. am I correct?

Comment: did you write different code for `Camera1` than `Camera2`?  If not then you ARE reusing code!  Do you really want to save your For/Each loops and `Select Case` statements to a DB?  Why, when the ones in your code work just fine.  So, what exactly so you want to save?

Comment: these are the things that I wanted to save : 
`New PointLatLng()`for the markers' location even after closing the app
and new instaces of form2:
`f2c1.AxxDec1.Camera=1`
`f2c2.AxxDec1.Camera=2` and each of the new instances contains 7 lines of codes. to make it simple, I want to run another and another after dynamically adding a marker and use the code with new instance and new camera.. getting it? if there is some other way, let me know.

Comment: there is a way to do WHAT you want, just not HOW you think you need to do it.  Consider a simple Camera: it has a Lat, Long, maybe Elevation, Zoom, DirectionFacing and 2-3 other "settings".  To recreate that from saved data, you simply need those settings.  Load them, perhaps thru a new procedure called LoadData which calls **existing** code to properly initialize the Camera and secondary objects to restore/recreate your app/objects to the same **state** they were.  You do not need to save code.  Look at a form's 'xxx.designer.vb': that is how VB recreates forms - just a some prop assignments.

Comment: I do get you now. Can you give me a little sample of that? I think that's what I really need. like function that will recreate the data from existing code with different values (values which I mean surely needs to be in the database)

Comment: I suspect, your Camera class is really a form, which complicates things a bit, but the examples I gave like Lat/Long/El/Zoom would just be properties.  Instead of getting the vals from a user, something like a CamSettings class would read them from somewhere, feed them to the Camera, then maybe call Camera.ApplySettings, which would tell it to go to that spot etc.  More importantly for every **key** variable you create - ask yourself IF it will be needed for reloading and then how will it get fed back to it so you can make the reload code part of everything from the start.

Comment: see updated question. hope you can get more grasp. I was hoping if you could give some sample from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Class Camera
   private _myCam As I_AM_NOT_SURE

   _Lat As Single = 0
   Friend Property Latitude As Single
        Get
            Return _Lat 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Single)
            _Lat = value
        End Set
   End Property

   _Long As Single = 0
   Friend Property Longitude As Single
        Get
            Return _Long 
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Single)
            _Long = value
        End Set
   End Property

   ' a way to make the camera take care of itself:
  Public Sub CreateView

     myCam = New GMapMarkerGoogleGreen( _
             New PointLatLng(_Lat, _Long ))

    ... the rest of that code
  End Sub
```

Your code seems inside out to me from here.  The Camera should not only manage the settings but also create the "view".  Most of the literals in your code are variables and can be saved/read etc Lat/Long seems the most important.  When saving, get the values from the class and save to where ever:

```
 dbLat var.... = Camera1.Latitude
 dbLong var.... = Camera1.Longitude
```

Then put them back.  Read the data from your db and:

```
 Dim Camera1 as New Camera

 Camera1.Longitude = dt.row(0)("Longitude")
 Camera1.Latitude = dt.row(0)("Latitude")
  ... etc
 End With

 Camera1.CreateView      ' create the view (?)
```

very rough, but I dont have a lot to go on, but the principle of variables and exposing them thru properties is the point of this.

Comment: it is how you push data (like a Lat value) to the camera class (Set), or get the value OUT of it to save to db (Get).  it is just like the Properties on VB FOrms and Objects: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/zzh9ha57.aspx   think of them as wrappers for the variables _Lat and _Long